# If two signals have different distributions that you know and can model, can you use that to separate them?

Tags: source-separation, probability-distribution-function

For example, if I have a mixed signal composed of signal A added to signal B, and I know that the histogram of signal A is non-Gaussian in the time domain, and that the histogram of signal B is Gaussian in the time domain, is there a way to isolate either A or B using this information?

I understand that I can use MLE or some similar method to fit a Gaussian to signal B, but I'm not sure where I'd go from there. My initial idea was to create a Gaussian filter that matches the distribution of signal B, and use that to separate B from A+B, but I'm not sure how I would implement that in practice, or if that even makes sense.

Any insights would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> If two signals have different distributions that you know and can model, can you use that to separate them?

Statistically, yes. Does that mean you can be certain *at any point in time*? No. But it allows you to transport data.

> For example, if I have a mixed signal composed of signal A added to signal B, and I know that the histogram of signal A is non-Gaussian in the time domain, and that the histogram of signal B is Gaussian in the time domain, is there a way to isolate either A or B using this information?

Not to separate them, but to use both to transport data independetly: For example, you can switch the Gaussian source on and off, and detect the presence of it.

> I understand that I can use MLE or some similar method to fit a Gaussian to signal B

Uff, you don't "fit" a Gaussian to something that has a distribution like a Gaussian. I know this sounds like nitpicking, but in these contexts, it's **very** important to make a distinction between the shape of the signal and the signal's amplitude distribution.

> My initial idea was to create a Gaussian filter that matches the distribution of signal B, and use that to separate B from A+B, but I'm not sure how I would implement that in practice, or if that even makes sense.

Doesn't make sense, far as I can tell.

I'm afraid you'll have to look into *information theory* a bit, and there into what *mutual information* is, how we model that, and noise.

You can then make general statements on the ability of A to transport data in the presence of B, considering the latter "noise". It also works the other way around!

This directly leads to the *successive cancellation decoder*, where you first (try to) decide the better receivable variable, then subtract the decision from the observation, then decode the other. For example:

Your A is discretely uniformly distributed on ${-2, -1.9, -1.8, \ldots , -0.1, 0, +0.1,\ldots +2\$, your B is Gaussian with zero mean and variance 0.01. You observe  Y = A+B = -1.52; you decide that by far the most likely value for A is -1.5, and with that knowledge you can infer that B must have been -0.02.

You needed distribution knowledge of A and B here to decide which of the two to decode first, and then to make a maximum-likelihood decision on A.

This successive method gives you a lower bound for your ability to get data from A+B given their distributions. However, that's not the same as a joint decoding. General, for a maximum likelihood estimator, you'd need to know the *joint* distribution of A and B under A+B; then you can, for any A+B, tell the most likely A and B. There's to my knowledge no general formula for this decoding – it really depends on the distributions. Also note that if A and B are statistically independent, this joint density will fall apart into the product of the individual densities. Note, however, also that usually, both A and B will employ channel coding, so that these likelihoods are both time-variant and depend on other decisions – welcome to the wonderful world of coding theory.